# access to child variable pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I am trying to access the child variable of the object through the parent

```
declare
  i a22;
  i1 VARCHAR(10);
begin
  i := a22('a22', t_b1(
                       b22('b22', t_a1(a22('a22_2', t_b1(b22('b22_2', t_a1())))))
                       )


           );

   dbms_output.put_line('i.name_a1='||i.name_a1);
   dbms_output.put_line('i.t_b1(1).name_b1='||i.o_b(1).name_b1);
   dbms_output.put_line('i.o_b(1).o_a(1).name_a1='||i.o_b(1).o_a(1).name_a1);
end;
/
```

When compiling, an error occurs indicating that the variable needs to be declared. It is logical that the parent does not know about the variables of the child object. But when initializing everything
successfully. How can I access a child variable?

The objects themselves:

```
Create type a1 is object (
  name_a1 varchar2(10)
) NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE;

Create type b1 is object (
  name_b1 varchar2(10)
) NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE;

create type t_a1 is table of a1;
create type t_b1 is table of b1;

Create type b22 UNDER b1 (
  o_a t_a1
) INSTANTIABLE;

Create type a22 UNDER a1 (
  o_b t_b1
) INSTANTIABLE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`TREAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions198.htm) function to access attributes of object subtypes.

Since `o_b` is of the type `table of b1` you have to treat  the object `o_b(1)` as `b22` because only `b22` object contains the member of type `table of a1`

```
dbms_output.put_line('i.o_b(1).o_a(1).name_a1='||treat(i.o_b(1) as b22).o_a(1).name_a1);
```

**Result:**

```
dbms_output:
i.o_b(1).o_a(1).name_a1=a22_2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d5869f1e459b3e729ebb8e6860792b1b)*